# Supress 6.0 permission model to work like before Android M

Tags: android, android-permissions

Is there a way to supress the new Android M permissions model other than setting the target SDK to 22?

**Word of explanation:**

We have a quite complex app and upgrading to the new permission will take some considerable amount of time, which (as may be expected) we don't have.

Our project is setup to use the newest build tools which (as I belive) require the target SDK to be 23.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to supress the new Android M permissions model other than setting the target SDK to 22?

No.

> Our project is setup to use the newest build tools which (as I belive) require the target SDK to be 23.

No. The build tools do not care about the `targetSdkVersion`.

Comment: i guess what he meant is the support libraries. i could be wrong

Comment: @k0sh: The support libraries require a matching `compileSdkVersion`. So, if you are using `23.0.1` of the support libraries, you need a `compileSdkVersion` of 23.

Comment: @CommonsWare wow didn't expect your answer here! Love your book! To the topic: If I leave the `compileSdkVersion` at 23 and set the `targetSdkVersion` to 22 will I both: the old permission model and new support libraries working?

Comment: @MarcinKunert: AFAIK, that combination survives. I have had stranger combinations than that. :-) The critical bit for the support libraries is the `compileSdkVersion`, as they may conditionally use new theme attributes and stuff, and so not having the right `compileSdkVersion` can break the build. I am not aware of a requirement of the support libraries with respect to `targetSdkVersion`. That being said, all else being equal, I'd try to keep the support libraries at the `targetSdkVersion`, but that's an objective, not a requirement, AFAIK. And thanks for the kind words!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you set your targetSdk and build tools to 23 if you aren't going to use any features of API level 23?

I would suggest just step down your targetSdk and build tools to 22 or whichever you were using earlier.

Comment: I guess that's the solution here. As far I understand the newest build tools included some sweet build time improvements.

Comment: yes, but to avail that build time improvement from the tools you will have to adjust to the other constraints of using the build tools version, like handling the permissions as that version of tools is designed to handle them